# Does Apple allow customers to play over Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a beginner in app development so sorry if my question is cheap :(

I wanted to start developing a card game and i was wondering if apple allows customers to play over Bluetooth or not ( on multiplayer )

I asked this question because i did not want to go all the way and realize that my game does not work over Bluetooth.

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132174/ios-recieve-data-from-bluetooth-and-then-send-information-to-a-database-on-anoth#9132423

Answer (score 1):

Look into the Multipeer Connectivity Framework from apple. It doesn't exclusively use bluetooth but it's meant for the type of connections you're describing. It uses Bluetooth, infrastructure wifi, and peer-to-peer wifi, depending on what's available.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/